# Is there a better way to prove these series for convergence or divergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

1. $\dfrac{1 \cdot 3\ldots2n-1}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6\ldots2n}$
2. $\dfrac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6\ldots2n}{1 \cdot 3\ldots2n+1}$
3. $\dfrac{1 \cdot 3\ldots2n-1}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6\ldots2n} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2n+1}$

I know these can be done by Raebe's Test, I wanted to know. Can I use a simpler test like Alembert, Cauchy root, or something else to do it because I was told that though Raebe is kind of stronger but its more complicated so one should try to find simpler proofs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use the stirling formula :
$$n! \sim \left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}$$
For example, for the first series we have :
$$\dfrac{1.3.\cdots.(2 n - 1)}{2.4.\dots.(2 n)} = \dfrac{(2 n)!}{4^n n!^2}$$
and by the stirling formula :
$$(2 n)! \sim \left(\dfrac{2 n}{e}\right)^{2 n} \sqrt{4 \pi n}$$
and :
$$(n!)^2 \sim \left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{2 n} (2 \pi n)$$
then :
$$\dfrac{(2 n)!}{4^n n!^2} \sim \dfrac{1}{4^n} \left(\dfrac{2 n}{e}\right)^{2 n} \sqrt{4 \pi n} \left(\dfrac{e}{n}\right)^{2 n} \dfrac{1}{2 \pi n} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$
And because the series :
$$\sum \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
diverges we conclude that the series :
$$\sum \dfrac{1.3.\cdots.(2 n - 1)}{2.4.\dots.(2 n)}$$
diverges.